# How to programatically construct a large cell array

Tags: matlab, dataset

How could I construct automatically a dataset like the one below, assuming that the number of columns of matrix summary_whts is approx. 400???

```
lrwghts = dataset(...
         {summary_whts(:,01),'w00'},...
         {summary_whts(:,02),'w01'},...
         {summary_whts(:,03),'w02'},...
         {summary_whts(:,04),'w03'},...
         {summary_whts(:,05),'w04'},...
         {summary_whts(:,06),'w05'},...
         {summary_whts(:,07),'w06'},...
         {summary_whts(:,08),'w07'},...
         {summary_whts(:,09),'w08'},...
         {summary_whts(:,10),'w09'},...
         {summary_whts(:,11),'w10'},...
         {summary_whts(:,12),'w11'},...
         'ObsNames',summary_mthd);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found it! This is what I was looking for:

```
cat = [];
for i = 0:(size(X,2)),
    cat = [cat;sprintf('w%03d',i)];
end
cat = cellstr(cat);
lrwghts = dataset({summary_whts,cat{:}},'ObsNames',cellstr(summary_mthd));
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a simple loop to populate `dataset`?

```
nCols = size(summary_whts,1);
dataset = cell(nCols, 2);
for i = 1:nCols
  dataset{i,1} = summary_whts(:,i);
  dataset{i,2} = sprintf('w%04d', i);
end
dataset{end+1,1} = 'ObsNames';
dataset(end, 2} = summary_mthd;
```

Comment: Thank you slayton, but would it be possible to work out the "dataset" solution? It seems not so difficult, but I can't figure out how to do that programatically...

Comment: I have no clue what the `summary_whts` or `dataset` variables you are working with look like so I've provided a general solution.